# Eager loading of relations

Tags: rust, orm, eager-loading, rust-diesel

I have three models with these relations:

Artist 1<->n Song 1<->n Play

I want to load Plays and eagerly load its Songs and its Artists.

I did this in PHP framework Eloquent easily. And it takes only 3 DB requests (one for each model).

Is this some how possible with diesel?

I think the Play model should look something like this:

```rust
#[derive(Queryable, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Play {
    pub id: u64,
    pub song_id: u64,
    pub song: Song, // <-- ????
    pub date: NaiveDateTime,
    pub station_id: u64,
}
```

And loading something like this:

```rust
// loads one model only at the moment
// it should load the related models Song and Artist too
let items = plays.filter(date.between(date_from, date_to)).load(&*conn)?;
```

The resulting struct should be JSON serialized to be used by the REST API. But I can't find a way to get the needed struct in one simple and efficient way.

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is to join the two other tables. I did not figure out how to avoid enumerating all table fields unfortunately. This is not an elegant solution, but it should work.

```
fn select_plays_with_song_and_artist(
    conn: &Conn,
    date_from: NaiveDate,
    date_to: NaiveDate,
) -> Result<Vec<(models::Play, models::Song, models::Artist)>> {
    plays::table                
    .filter(plays::date.between(date_from, date_to))               
    .join(songs::table.join(artists::table))                                             
    .select((                                                               
        (
            plays::id,  
            plays::song_id,     
            plays::date,     
            plays::station_id,                                      
        ),
        (
            songs::id,
            // other relevant fields...
        ),
        (
            artist::id,
            // other relevant fields...
        ),
     ))                                                                           
     .load::<(models::Play, models::Song, models::Artist)>(conn)
}
```

Comment: I found a similar solution in diesel docs. The problem with all of the is, I have to build my struct in a second step. I need it for a REST API. But there seems to be no way to get this in only one run.

Comment: This could normally be solved by just putting everything into a struct and then use `#[serde(flatten)]` there for some parts of the struct.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: If you post a question about diesel online, please always include the relevant part of your schema, otherwise others need to guess how it looks like.
I will assume the following schema for your question:

```rust
table! {
    plays (id)
       id -> BigInt,
       song_id -> BigInt,
       date -> Timestamp,
       station_id -> BigInt,
    }

}

table! {
    songs(id) {
        id -> BigInt,
        name -> Text,
    }
}

joinable!(plays -> songs (song_id));
```

Now there is some issue with your `Play` struct. `u64` is not a type supported by diesel. Checkout [this](https://docs.diesel.rs/1.4.x/diesel/sql_types/struct.BigInt.html) documentation about which types are compatible with a `BigInt` SQL type.
That means I will assume the following structs implementing `Queryable`:

```rust
#[derive(Queryable, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Play {
    pub id: i64,
//    pub song_id: u64, leave this out as it is a duplicate with `song` below
    pub song: Song,
    pub date: NaiveDateTime,
    pub station_id: i64,
}

#[derive(Queryable, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Song {
    pub id: i64,
    pub name: String,
}
```

Now to come to your core question: At first, diesel does not have the concept of a single model like known from other ORM's. If you have ever used such a thing, don't try to apply that knowledge to diesel, it won't work. There are a set of traits describing a capability of each struct. As we are talking about querying here I will concentrate on `Queryable`. `Queryable` is designed to map the result of a query (which could include zero, one or more tables) to a rust data structure. By default (by using the `derive`) it does this by mapping fields structural, that means your select clause needs to match the structure deriving `Queryable`.
Now back to your concrete problem. It means that we must construct a query that returns `(i64, (i64, String), NaiveDateTime, i64)` (or better the fields with the corresponding SQL types).
For this case this is as easy as using a single join:

```rust
plays::table.inner_join(songs::table)
   .select((plays::id, songs::all_columns, plays::date, plays::station_id))
```

The only important thing here for the mapping is the select clause. You can append/prepend whatever other `QueryDsl` method you like.

Comment: So I have my models with foreign IDs and query `Vec<(Play, Song, Artist)>`. Then I 
 `map()` the result to another model that contains the references model instead of the ID:  `FullPlay{..., song: FullSong, ...}`. Correct?

Comment: I did it now this way. GIves me the needed result and is faster than expected.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anything elegant way of doing this. Here's the snippet, if you want to do it in two steps.

First, get the both models using join on both table.

```rust
impl Comment {
    pub fn list(conn: &PgConnection, page_id: i32) -> Result<Vec<(Comment, User)>, Error> {
        use crate::schema::users;

        comment::table
            .inner_join(users::table)
            .select((comment::all_columns, users::all_columns))
            .filter(comment::page_id.eq(page_id))
            .load(conn)
    }
}
```

Now, iterate over the result to make it fit into your own api response structure.

```rust
#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct CommentListResponse {
    #[serde(flatten)]
    pub comment: Comment,
    pub user: UserResponse
}
```

```rust
    let result = Comment::list(&connection, page.id)?;


    let mut comment_list = vec![];

    for (comment, user) in result {
        let cr = CommentListResponse {
            comment,
            user: UserResponse::from(user),
        };
        comment_list.push(cr);
    }

    Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().json(comment_list))
```